# SharePoint Linq ToList ArgoumentException

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, linq

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Foundation with LINQ for SharePoint list. I've generate my DataContext using spmetal command.

Now I'm trying to access data but I have this error:

> ArgoumentException error: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.

This is the code that crash:

```
        using (DataContext context = new DataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            List<MyListFieldsContentType> tasks = context.Task.Where(x => x.Code.Id == id).ToList();
```

I think that the problem is with .ToList() command because without .toList() I haven't error.

More details about error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMap.GetColumnNumber(String strFieldName, Boolean bThrow)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetColumnNumber(String groupName, Boolean bThrowException)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetRawValue(String fieldname, Int32 iIndex, Boolean bThrow)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_Item(String fieldName)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.PropertyMap.GetSPFieldValue(PropertyMap pm, SPListItem item, JoinPath joinPath)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.PropertyMap.GetFromListItem(DataContext dc, SPListItem item, Object entity, JoinPath joinPath)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPItemMappingInfo.MaterializeEntity[TEntity](DataContext dc, SPDataList list, SPListItem item, SPItemMappingInfo itemMappingInfo, JoinPath joinPath)
>      at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , SPListItem )
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Acm.DataAccessLayer.Acquisition.LinqDalAcquisitionTask.GetByAcquisitionId(Int32 id)
>      at AcquisitionTool.Layouts.AcquisitionTool.AllAcquisitionsGantt.GetChartData()

Please, can you help me?

Comment: You can use the data.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; before getting the data using .ToList()

Comment: Hi, I tried but without success. I've added this code: context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: Debugging my application I noticed that using quickwatch I need wait some second for view result.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

> It might possible that lookup fields were omitted from the query
>   results because the list exceeds the lookup column threshold.

To solve it, go to **Central Administrator -> Application management -> Manage Web Applications** select one, then on top **General Settings -> Resource Throttling** there change default (8) List View Lookup Threshold value to a bigger one, in my case 12 was the lowest accepted value.

**That's it! It might solve your issue...!**

You can get SharePoint List items using below mentioned code.

```
// Get DataContext from page context
using (DataContext context = new DataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{

        // Get the SharePoint list
        EntityList<Task> Customers = data.GetList<Task>("Task");

        var Tasks = from customer in Customers
                              where customer.Id == id
                              select customer;

        foreach (var Task in Tasks)
        {
            Console.Writeline("id = {0}, Task.CustomerId);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried but I obtain the same error in: var Task.

Comment: Than your entity is not bound properly

Comment: Thanks for your support. What can I do? I have not changed DataContext class.

Comment: can you please post the entire error? so i can help you better

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post with the stacktrace. There is not InnerException.

Comment: is my updated answer works for you?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure but I think that the cause of the problem are broken lookup columns. I've tried but without success with your update.

Comment: Ok So It means I was on a right track to suggest you a solution. :)....... Actually lookups are the first thing which we should look into in for DataContext.

Comment: If it helps you than please mark the answer so others can get atleast an idea from it. :) :)